# dplyr: group mean centering (mutate + summarize)

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the efficient/preferred way to do group mean centering with dplyr, that is take each element of a group (`mutate`) and perform an operation on it and a summary stat (`summarize`) for that group.  Here's how one might do group mean centering on `mtcars` using base R:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), function(x){ 
    x[["cent"]] <- x$mpg - mean(x$mpg)
    x
}))
```

Comment: That works didn't even try it because I didn't know you could use `group_by` on `mutate`.  Nice thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
      add_rownames()%>% #if the rownames are needed as a column
      group_by(cyl) %>% 
      mutate(cent= mpg-mean(mpg))
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the above code use the global mean to center the mpg; how should I do if I want to center at the within group mean, i.e. the mean values of each cyl group level are different.

```
> mtcars %>%
+   add_rownames()%>% #if the rownames are needed as a column
+   group_by(cyl) %>% 
+   mutate(cent= mpg-mean(mpg))%>%
+   dplyr ::select(cent)
Adding missing grouping variables: `cyl`
# A tibble: 32 x 2
# Groups:   cyl [3]
     cyl   cent
   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     6  0.909
 2     6  0.909
 3     4  2.71 
 4     6  1.31 
 5     8 -1.39 
 6     6 -1.99 
 7     8 -5.79 
 8     4  4.31 
 9     4  2.71 
10     6 -0.891
# … with 22 more rows
Warning message:
Deprecated, use tibble::rownames_to_column() instead. 
> mtcars$mpg[1:5]-mean(mtcars$mpg)
[1]  0.909375  0.909375  2.709375  1.309375 -1.390625
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead (although the name of the new variable displayed is different):

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(gpcent = scale(mpg, scale = F))
```